# Анализ кортежа по трем величинам

Tags: python, python-3.x, group-by

Есть кортеж

```py
data = [['Id-a', '№1', 2.0], ['Id-b', '№1', 4.0], ['Id-b', '№2', 3.0], 
['Id-a', '№1', 6.0], ['Id-a', '№2', 2.0], ['Id-c', '№1', 9.0], 
['Id-b', '№2', 1.0], ['Id-c', '№2', 7.0], ['Id-b', '№2', 5.0], ['Id-c', '№1', 2.0]]
```

Id, принадлежность к группе и число. Необходимо сложить числа в одинаковых группах и Id и вывести в следующем виде:

```
['Id-a', '№1', 8.0]
['Id-a', '№2', 2.0] 
['Id-b', '№1', 4.0] 
['Id-b', '№2', 9.0]
['Id-c', '№1', 11.0] 
['Id-c', '№2', 7.0]]
```

Получилось суммировать значения только по Id:

```py
# создаю список id
id=[] 
for r in data:
    id.append(r[0])
# суммирую числа по id    
res =[]
for k in set(id):
    summ = 0
    for s in data:
        if k==s[0]:
            summ = summ + s[2]
            t = [k, summ]            
    res.append(t)


print (res)  
# [['Id-a', 10.0], ['Id-b', 13.0], ['Id-c', 18.0]]
```

Как дополнить код, чтобы суммировать числа по Id и группам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
In [42]: from itertools import groupby

In [43]: res = [[c[0], c[1], sum(z[2] for z in g)] 
                for c,g in groupby(sorted(data), key=lambda x: x[:2])]

In [44]: res
Out[44]:
[['Id-a', '№1', 8.0],
 ['Id-a', '№2', 2.0],
 ['Id-b', '№1', 4.0],
 ['Id-b', '№2', 9.0],
 ['Id-c', '№1', 11.0],
 ['Id-c', '№2', 7.0]]
```